# Is it okay to take subject common and maintain parallelism?

Tags: parallelism

I was wondering if it is okay to take the subject common from a sentence and if the parallelism would be maintained. e.g.,

```
I went to the party and I had whiskey in the party.
```

is converted to

```
I went to the party and had whiskey in the party.
```

Is the sentence 2 correct and are such formations correct?

Comment: Yes, but it's stylistically inelegant in having "the party" twice. A simple alternative night be "I went to the party and had whiskey to drink".

Comment: Note that it's stylistically common to separate independent clauses with a comma (the first sentence), even if the subject of the second clause is omitted (the second sentence). The more obvious that it's written as an independent clause, or the longer it is, the more likely a comma is to be used.

Comment: You're off-topic yet again. The OP didn't ask about punctuation! In any case, the first sentence does not need a comma, and in the second sentence the second coordinate "and had whiskey in the party" is not an independent clause.

Comment: @BillJ — People in glass houses. You’re abusing the comment facility by answering the question, rather than asking for clarification or suggesting an improvement.

Comment: No relation to the question, of course, but for your reference, the phrase is "at the party" and not "in the party".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Analysis is awkward when there are multiple issues to address; 'at the party' is idiomatic.

Repeated elements are often clumsy; here, 'at the party' grates more than a repeated 'I'.

- 'I went to the party, and I drank whiskey'

sounds most natural.

- 'I went to the party and drank whiskey'

is perfectly grammatical, but would usually be used only in response to say 'I hope you're avoiding alcohol as the doctor said, George – I hope you didn't go to that party on Saturday.' The two statements are more cohesive in this riposte, making the deletion of 'I' more fitting.

Comment: I find "I went to the party and drank whiskey" to be natural. I wouldn't use "I went to the party and I drank whiskey" unless I was trying to separate the statements, as for example if I drank whiskey after I returned home.

Comment: With no context other than the knowledge that there had been a party, 'I went to the party and met some really interesting people' sounds totally natural. 'I went to the party and I sat on various different chairs' sounds ridiculous. I'd put 'I went to the party and I drank whiskey' somewhere in between.